# Computing the area between 2 curves

Tags: calculus, integration, area

$x+y = 5$ and  $x+7 = y^2$.
$$$$
It is possible to calculate the area between two curves as follows:

$\int_a^b f(x) dx$ + $\int_b^c g(x) dx$. Where a = ___
, b____, c_____ and $f(x) = $________ and $g(x)=$________

Alternatively, this area can be calculated as a single integral:
$\int_z^w t(y) dy$.
Where z = ___
, w____ and $t(y) = $________
$$$$
My answers was:
a = -4, b = 0, c = 3. f(x) = 5-y and g(x) = $y^2 - 7
$$$$$
And z = -4,w = 3 and t(y) = $-y^2 -y + 12$. The value final is: $\cfrac{343}{6}$

I'm correct?

Comment: You write $f(x)$ with an $x$ as the argument equal to $5-y$ with a $y$ as the variable.  You repeat this mistake with $g(x)$.  While I agree, it may make more sense to phrase this as integrals with respect to $y$ that is not what is asked of you.

Comment: The first part talking about integrals of $f$ and $g$ being functions of $x$ is talking about describing the area as a sum of vertical bars.  It may help to look at a [graph of the situation](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%2By%3D5%2C+x%2B7%3Dy%5E2).  The reason why we split it into two integrals is because on the left side the vertical bars would range from a point on the upper part of the parabola to the lower part of the parabola while on the right side the vertical bars would range from a point on the upper part on the line to the lower part on the parabola.

Comment: You mean I can't isolate y as f (x), but isolate x? Are the intervals correct at first?

Comment: No, your intervals are not correct because you are stuck thinking about ranging over values of $y$ when we should have been ranging over values of $x$.

Comment: You say that I need to isolate y = 5-x; y = (+ -) sqrt (x + 7)? I don't understanding

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a screengrab of the the two curves and the region between them.  Pardon the not straight lines.

[image]

One can describe and calculate the area of the region using *vertical* bars.  That is what the first half of the problem is trying to get you to describe this problem as using integrals where you integrate over values of $x$.

The area can be described as the area of the blue region which follows one pattern (*upper edge of the rectangles lying on the upper part of the parabola*) as well as the area of the red region which follows a different pattern (*upper edge of the rectangles lying on the line*).

So, we try to describe the area as the sum of two integrals each of which with respect to $x$.  To do this, we first ask... what $x$ values correspond to the blue region?  What $x$ values correspond to the red region?

> $-7\leq x\leq 2$ for the blue region.  $2\leq x\leq 9$ for the red region.

Next, given a particular $x$ in the blue region, what is the height of the corresponding rectangle?

> It ranges from the top part of the parabola to the bottom part, i.e. ranges from $+\sqrt{x+7}$ to $-\sqrt{x+7}$.  The height is then the difference of these: $2\sqrt{x+7}$

Given a particular $x$ in the red region, what is the height of the corresponding rectangle?

> It ranges from the top being the line to the bottom being the parabola, i.e. ranges from $5-x$ to $-\sqrt{x+7}$.  The height is the difference of these: $5-x+\sqrt{x+7}$

Finally, we can describe the area using these setting it up as integrals:

> $\int\limits_{-7}^2 (2\sqrt{x+7})\text{d}x + \int\limits_2^9(5-x+\sqrt{x+7})\text{d}x$

The second half of the problem has you dealing with describing the area as an integral with respect to $y$ by effectively adding up the areas of multiple *horizontal* rectangles.  This is perhaps easier as you don't have to mess with messy square roots and you don't need to break the region up into multiple pieces to handle separately since for every choice of $y$ the width of such a rectangle follows the same pattern.

Comment: My answer the second half is wrong or make correct? I trying undestand your first explain haha

Comment: Your answer for the second half was correct.  The whole point to take away from this exercise is that when integrating you may choose to do so horizontally or vertically, but some choices will lead to more work and other choices may be easier.  When getting into more complicated situations as well, how you choose to approach an integral will potentially drastically reduce the difficulty (*e.g. by converting to polar coordinates or similar*)